# Interaction failed with Discord buttons using discord.py and DiscordComponents bot?

Tags: python, бот, discord, button

I'm trying to use a Discord bot to get user interaction on messages through buttons.The buttons are created just fine and appear as expected, but no matter what I try I'm unable to get input and am greeted with "This interaction failed" on each button press: [discord error][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Here's the code I'm testing with.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
TOKEN = ''
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=intents)
 class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
 @bot.event
 async def on_ready():   
       print(f"Connecté en tant que {bot.user} !")
@bot.command()
async def ghost(ctx):
    try:
        button1 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label="карточка", custom_id="bouton1")
        button2 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, label="характеристика", custom_id="bouton2")
        button3 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, label="призрак", custom_id="bouton3")
        button4 = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.danger, label="локация", custom_id="bouton4")      
        view = discord.ui.View()
        view.add_item(button1)
        view.add_item(button2)
        view.add_item(button3)
        view.add_item(button4)   
        await ctx.send("Да, начнеться веселье:)", view=view)
        def check(interaction):
            return interaction.user.id == ctx.author.id and interaction.message.id == ctx.message.id
        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)

        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
        if interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton1":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 1 cliqué !")
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton2":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 2 cliqué !")
            random_number = random.randint(1, 100)  # Генерация случайного числа от 1 до 100
            await interaction.respond(content=f"Случайное число: {random_number}")
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton3":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 3 cliqué !")
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "bouton4":
            await interaction.respond(content="Bouton 4 cliqué !")    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Une erreur s'est produite : {e}")
pass
bot.run('')
```

Is there something wrong with this code?

If discord_components is no longer a viable solution, is there another package I can turn to that has a discord bot object and can implement buttons? and if it's not difficult, then you can write how to write correctly with randomness, not with numbers, but with words in lines.
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: У вас нет что-ли  переводчика в гугле или яндексе?

Comment: Ну, вот у вас видимо нет, а значит, что и у меня тоже нет. А если серьёзно, то согласно правилам  сайта вопросы и ответы должны быть на русском языке. В противном случае они удаляются, что вполне правильно: это *русскоязычная* версия сайта stackoverflow.